# Python Script does not terminate properly

Tags: python, debugging, pyqt

I have a python script which I call using `python main.py` on my terminal. It starts a Qt-GUI which executes properly and terminates when I close the GUI.

However, sometimes the last debug message "over and out" is printed but the script itself does not terminate. Neither <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> nor <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> have any impact on the execution. It seems to me as if this happens when an exception was thrown inside the program (and caught by the GUI).

I do not know how to debug this since it obviously does not happen in the GUI itself. How do I debug this and find out, what I did wrong?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys 

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MainGui()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()
    print "over and out"
```

EDIT: It seems to me as if there is some thread still being active in the end. However, I do not explicetely work with thread (I do not know what Qt does internally...). Is there a way to view all running threads in the end?

EDIT2: Oh my f*ing god. The solution simply was restarting my system. Somehow my OS did some crazy stuff and prevented the script from terminating.

Comment: Can you create a reasonably small test case that reliably reproduces the problem? Very often, attempting to do this will either lead you directly to a solution, or, at the very least, isolate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution simply was restarting my system. Somehow my OS did some crazy stuff and prevented the script from terminating.

Comment: Ironically not windows. Mac OS. ;)

Answer (score 1):

**"Neither <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> nor <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> have any impact on the execution."**

Add these lines of code to the header of your program and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> will exit it.

```
import signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
```

And if you want to automatically go into the pdb debugger when your program hits an exception, just do this:

```
import sys

def excepthook(type_, value, tb):
    import pdb
    import traceback

    # print the exception...
    traceback.print_exception(type_, value, tb)
    print
    # ...then start the debugger in post-mortem mode
    pdb.pm()

# we are NOT in interactive mode
if not hasattr(sys, 'ps1') or sys.stderr.target.isatty():
    # this stops PyQt from freezing the terminal
    from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtRemoveInputHook
    pyqtRemoveInputHook()

    sys.excepthook = excepthook
```

Comment: ctrl+c does work before the GUI has closed. When the script reaches this "dead point" after the print message ctrl+c does not work anymore - even with your code inserted.

pdb-debugger does work if i do not catch the exception in my code. So far that did not help me with my problem, because it only occurs after everything else is already terminated. 

I do not get it :(